# Localesidkey value for palestine country

Tags: apex, customer-portal, localization

HI I am trying to insert Palestine portal user using apex code, and using ar_PS as a localesidkey but sales force throwing 'bad restricted pick list value'. can anyone tell correct locale code Palestine country that sales force support.

Comment: You can find supported locales in salesforce here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&type=5

Comment: i couldn't find for Palestine country there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would seem to be a very difficult one since [Palestine](https://www.mapsofworld.com/palestine/) is in the West Bank, parts of which are occupied by Israel. On the Arabic side, it directly borders Jordan to the East (ar_JO), Syria (ar_SY) is to the NE and Lebanon (ar_LB) is to the North. You'll need to choose one of those three. The time zone should be [EEST](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/eest).